# How can I find hidden object in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, object-styles

I want to show the object which I marked as hidden before.

How can I find hidden objects in Inkscape?

Answer (score 14):

- open the find/replace tab - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- in the `Find:` section type:

  ```
  display:none
  ```
- in the `Search in` section select `Properties`
- in the `General` section select `Include hidden`
- in the `Properties` section select `Style`
- click the `Find` button

[image: find hidden fields]

Comment: Also see [Inkscape documentation](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Select.html)

Comment: This did not work for me. Came up no object found, when I can still see it with edit paths by nodes function.
Inkscape can hide things with one click, pulling them out of hiding seems to be impossible on my system. People complain of having to resort to coding, and that is more work than one click, but none of the coding worked for me.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this worked perfectly for me. And I suggest following the documentation link by @djvg , as there are additional options there.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Shift+X to open the xml editor and select the object without stroke/fill. It will automatically select the item in the main editor/canvas.

[image]